# Jquery alert with button and when clicked load a dirrent page

Tags: jquery

I am working on an "alert", so far so good.
When the alert is triggered I want the button to load a URL.

This is my code:

```
$.alert({
  title: 'Room display errors!',
  content: 'Room ' + result + '<BR/>',
  icon: 'fa fa-rocket',
  animation: 'zoom',
  boxWidth: '50%',
  closeAnimation: 'zoom',
  buttons: {
    okay: {
      text: 'Acknowledge',
      btnClass: 'btn-blue'
      window.top.location.href = 'confmon_a.php', // ERROR HERE
    }
  },

cancel: function() {
  $.alert('canceled');
}
});
```

At the moment the console displays: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier on the line "Error Here". The alert works until I add this line of code.

Can anyone see where I am going wrong.

Many thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Missing a comma on the line above

Comment: @Ray Nicholus thanks for your time. Did not see that but after making the correction I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add comma after `btnClass: 'btn-blue'`, and insert `window.top.location.href = 'confmon_a.php'` to a function, like:

```
buttons: {
  okay: {
    text: 'Acknowledge',
    btnClass: 'btn-blue',
    action: function() {
      window.top.location.href = 'confmon_a.php';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Good catch, I didn’t even see the equals sign for some reason, and the bizarre property reference. Wow was this code a disaster!

Answer (score 0):

Add " , "  after  " btnClass

```
    okay: {
        text: 'Acknowledge',
        btnClass: 'btn-blue',
        window.top.location.href = 'confmon_a.php', 
     }
```

Comment: Hi all, I have tried all the comments but they all produce the following error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :"

Comment: @Chayim Friedman Just tried your answer again and it worked. I must have coded it wrong. Many thanks.